# convert "m.d.yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd" using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i convert a string of format "d.m.yyyy" to another format say "yyyy-mm-dd" using javascipt?
I have tried using new Date('9.5.1989').but its not working.

Comment: Do you just want to change the string, or do you want an actual `Date` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pad(number, length) { 
    var str = String(number);
    return (str.length >= length) ? str : ( new Array(length - str.length + 1).join('0') ) + str;
}

var pieces = "10.2.2012".split('.');
var wanted = pieces[2] + '-' + pad(pieces[0], 2) + '-' + pad(pieces[1], 2);
```

After this, the result is in the `wanted` variable

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
new Date('9.5.1989'     // your input string
          .split(/\./)  // split into [9,5,1989]
          .reverse()    // reverse into [1989,5,9]
          .join('/')    // join into '1989/5/9', which is valid input for Date
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the result as a `string` and not a `Date`, you can try something like:

```
var d = new Date('9.5.1989');​
var str = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1 /*months are 0 based */) + "-" + d.getDate();
alert(str);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Try next code to get Date object
    var tmp = str.split('.');
    var dateObj = new Date(tmp[2], tmp[0], tmp[1]);
And then format it as you want. You can use jQuery dateFormat plugin if you use jquery library.